# Timestamps Id value in WCF request with Certificate credential type

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

In my application I'm calling WCF service using basicHttpBinding with below settings:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_SSL_MessageCertificate">
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
        </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Request after it is signed looks like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <ActivityId CorrelationId="520e6278-efba-4ec0-87a8-5d94f31d8820" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ActivityId>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
                <u:Created>2019-11-15T11:33:17.273Z</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>2019-11-15T11:38:17.273Z</u:Expires>
            </u:Timestamp>
            <o:BinarySecurityToken>
                <!--Removed-->
            </o:BinarySecurityToken>
            <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <SignedInfo>
                    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                    <Reference URI="#_0">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <DigestValue>TmHWOnVBZg98YPSweh7X/HzDaOc=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                </SignedInfo>
                <SignatureValue><!--Removed--></SignatureValue>
                <KeyInfo>
                    <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <o:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#uuid-ad5f87dc-e951-4c24-8bc2-e94c1abfa7cc-214"/>
                    </o:SecurityTokenReference>
                </KeyInfo>
            </Signature>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <MessageBody>
            <!--Removed-->
        </MessageBody>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Problem: Id of Timestamp element is always "_0". Is there a way to change this, for example set Id to random Guid? Now with two requests (with different body) sent in the same time the signature value will be the same, and according to my client it is recognized as a replay attack. Is there anything I can do with this?